# WCF InvalidDataContractException: "Type cannot be serialized" but is marked correctly

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, datacontract, datamember

I am getting an InvalidDataContractException:

> Type 'LicenseWatchingServiceLibrary.LicenseInfoContainerExpiring' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it [...]

But it already is marked (see code). I already searched but none of the solutions i found worked for me. WCF is used here to communicate between a Windows Service and a ui application. Some code:

The bit that throws the exception, located in a windows wcf service application:

```
private void Run()
    {
        //[...]

        List<LicenseInfoContainerExpiring> expiringLicenses;
        List<LicenseInfoContainerUntrusted> untrustedLicenses;
        readLicenseInfoLists(out expiringLicenses, out untrustedLicenses, out warningNeeded);
        if (warningNeeded)
        {
            LWSProxy.WatchLicenses(expiringLicenses, untrustedLicenses); //breaks here
        }
    }
```

interface inside a class library

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ILicenseWatchingServiceUXHost
{
    [OperationContract]
    void WatchLicenses(List<LicenseInfoContainerExpiring> elcs, List<LicenseInfoContainerUntrusted> ulcs);
}
```

LicenseInfoContainerExpiring.cs, located in the class library as well: (all of it, just in case i forgot something somewhere)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace LicenseWatchingServiceLibrary
{
    [DataContract]
    public partial class LicenseInfoContainerExpiring : ILicenseInfoContainer
    {
        #region precode

        #region properties
        [DataMember]
        public string licenseName { get; private set; } 
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime licenseExpirationDate { get; private set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int licenseDaysUntilExpired { get; private set; } 
        [DataMember]
        public string licenseType { get; private set; } 
        [DataMember]
        public string licenseActivationID { get; private set; } 
        #endregion

        #region objects
        [DataMember]
        private CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US"); 
        #endregion

        #endregion

        #region constructor

        public LicenseInfoContainerExpiring() { }

        public LicenseInfoContainerExpiring(string name, string ID, string type, string expirationDate)
        {
            licenseName = name;
            licenseType = type;
            licenseActivationID = ID;

            //calculate expiration
            if (expirationDate != "permanent")
            {
                licenseDaysUntilExpired = (DateTime.ParseExact(expirationDate, "dd-MMM-yyyy", ci) - DateTime.Now.Date).Days;
            }
            else
            {
                licenseDaysUntilExpired = 9999999;
            }
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: If you use proxy generated by visual studio, try to recompile server, start it, update service reference on client and recompile client...

Comment: still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have data members with private setters. Then it can not be possible to set its values on deserialization. Make the setters public too.

And remember, you data contract is instantiated without calling even the default constructor on deserialization.

```
namespace LicenseWatchingServiceLibrary
{
    [DataContract]
    public partial class LicenseInfoContainerExpiring : ILicenseInfoContainer
    {
        #region precode

        #region properties
        [DataMember]
        public string licenseName { get; set; } 
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime licenseExpirationDate { get; set; }

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! but how do i prevent unintended use of the setters now?

Comment: As I know, there is no prevention. The way may be to not use exchange object in business layer and rather map this data to domain objects with all its restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Add KnownType:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(GregorianCalendar))]
public partial class LicenseInfoContainerExpiring : ILicenseInfoContainer
{}
```